# println in grails gsp file

Tags: grails, gsp

I know this is simple thing, but i was not aware.

I used println in gsp file and expected to print output in console. But this is showing on page.

```
<% 
for(int i =0; i < threads.size();i++) {
     println i
} 
%>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```
<%
   System.out.println i 
%>
```

But why use sniplets in a GSP page?

If you want console debug output from your GSP i suggest using this plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/debug

Comment: thank you sbglasius. if removed <%%> tags in gsp , it is showing ERROR pages.GroovyPagesTemplateEngine  - Compilation error compiling GSP

Comment: Ah, I didn't want you to remove the <% %> - so please leave them :-)